# Bad practice to call static function from external file via function pointer?

Tags: c++, c

Consider the following code:

file_1.hpp:

```
typedef void (*func_ptr)(void);

func_ptr file1_get_function(void);
```

file1.cpp:

```
// file_1.cpp
#include "file_1.hpp"
static void some_func(void)
{
    do_stuff();
}

func_ptr file1_get_function(void)
{
    return some_func;
}
```

file2.cpp

```
#include "file1.hpp"
void file2_func(void)
{
     func_ptr function_pointer_to_file1 = file1_get_function();
     function_pointer_to_file1();
}
```

While I believe the above example is technically possible - to call a function with internal linkage only via a function pointer, is it bad practice to do so?  Could there be some funky compiler optimizations that take place (auto inline, for instance) that would make this situation problematic?

Comment: The question is, why would it be useful? Why don't just make `some_func()` have external linkage? What you're doing doesn't make sense unless you can explain in what scenario it does make sense.

Comment: Interesting question but what's the need to do something like this really?

Comment: The code will work just fine. The danger will be to you personally from the next programmer who comes along and has to work on it.

Comment: There isn't a need.  I was reviewing some code where a static function, which has been in the code repo for awhile, was given out via function pointer, and I'm not sure whether or not I need to go back and remove the internal linkage.   More a maintainability question.

Comment: In that simple example it seems quite pointless. But in other situations it might make more sense. For example, if you have a function/vector table. Each vector would typically point to a static function. The vector table would be the only external symbol or would be returned via a public function call. This is one of the typical ways of implementing a plugin model.

Comment: It will work, and I have seen similar recommended for certain purposes -- specifically, for writing Python extensions.  You want Python to be able to call the interface functions (which it does via pointers), but you don't want them to be exposed to other code -- especially other extensions -- so you give them internal linkage.

Answer (score 1):

There's no problem, this is fine.  In fact , IMHO, it is a good practice which lets your function be called without polluting the space of externally visible symbols.

It would also be appropriate to use this technique in the context of a function lookup table, e.g. a calculator which passes in a string representing an operator name, and expects back a function pointer to the function for doing that operation.

The compiler/linker isn't allowed to make optimizations which break correct code and this is correct code.

Historical note: back in C89, externally visible symbols had to be unique on the first 6 characters; this was relaxed in C99 and also commonly by compiler extension.

Answer (score 0):

In order for this to work, you have to expose some portion of it as external and that's the clue most compilers will need.

Is there a chance that there's a broken compiler out there that will make mincemeat of this strange practice because they didn't foresee someone doing it? I can't answer that.

I can only think of false reasons to want to do this though: Finger print hiding, which fails because you have to expose it in the function pointer decl, unless you are planning to cast your way around things, in which case the question is "how badly is this going to hurt".

The other reason would be facading callbacks - you have some super-sensitive static local function in module m and you now want to expose the functionality in another module for callback purposes, but you want to audit that so you want a facade:

```
static void voodoo_function() {
}

fnptr get_voodoo_function(const char* file, int line) {
    // you tagged the question as C++, so C++ io it is.
    std::cout << "requested voodoo function from " << file << ":" << line << "\n";
    return voodoo_function;
}

...

// question tagged as c++, so I'm using c++ syntax
auto* fn = get_voodoo_function(__FILE__, __LINE__);
```

but that's not really helping much, you really want a wrapper around execution of the function.

At the end of the day, there is a much simpler way to expose a function pointer. Provide an accessor function.

```
static void voodoo_function() {}

void do_voodoo_function() {
    // provide external access to voodoo
    voodoo_function();
}
```

Because here you provide the compiler with an optimization opportunity - when you link, if you specify whole program optimization, it can detect that this is a facade that it can eliminate, because you let *it* worry about function pointers.

But is there a really compelling reason not just to remove the `static` from infront of `voodoo_function` other than not exposing the internal name for it? And if so, why is the internal name so precious that you would go to these lengths to hide that?

```
static void ban_account_if_user_is_ugly() {
    ...;
}

fnptr do_that_thing() {
    ban_account_if_user_is_ugly();
}
```

vs

```
void do_that_thing() { // ban account if user is ugly
    ...
}
```

--- EDIT ---

Conversion. Your function pointer is `int(*)(int)` but your static function is `unsigned int(*)(unsigned int)` and you don't want to have to cast it.

Again: Just providing a facade function would solve the problem, and it will transform into a function pointer later. Converting it to a function pointer by hand can only be a stumbling block for the compiler's whole program optimization.

But if you're casting, lets consider this:

```
// v1
fnptr get_fn_ptr() {
    // brute force cast because otherwise it's 'hassle'
    return (fnptr)(static_fn);
}

int facade_fn(int i) {
    auto ui = static_cast<unsigned int>(i);
    auto result = static_fn(ui);
    return static_cast<int>(result);
}
```

Ok unsigned to signed, not a big deal. And then someone comes along and changes what fnptr needs to be to `void(int, float);`. One of the above becomes a weird runtime crash and one becomes a compile error.